# Bootstrap vs. Wordpress Templates with Envato

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, templates, plugins, themes

I'm creating a website. I really want this certain theme/template I found on envato marketplace (www.market.envato.com) and was wondering if I could use Wordpress.org with it. This is the theme/template, its called metronic.

http://themeforest.net/item/metronic-responsive-admin-dashboard-template/4021469ref=keenthemes&ref=keenthemes&clickthrough_id=545787393&redirect_back=true

I want the certain theme, not only because it has 7 different themes that come with it, but it already has plugins. At least I think. My question is, is if this theme template will work with my wordpress website, and how I can get it on my website using wordpress if so. Also, I was wondering if this template came with plugins. (I'm really new to this stuff, so thanks for helping.)

Answer (score 0):

The theme you have linked to is an admin theme. This is for the wordpress "backend" or administrative pages. Is that your intention? Or are you looking for a theme that is user facing, like to share your content?

Comment: Well actually, I'd like to use it like this. This is the website I found and I want to make it look like this. www.csgobuddy.com . He used it in the sense of a template which I guess is user-facing?

Answer (score 0):

www.csgobuddy.com seems to have a simple WordPress theme. It does not have a backend theme like the one you purchased.

Metronic  theme that you purchased from Envato is not a WordPress theme, so you cannot use it with WordPress.

For use with Wordpress you can get themes here http://themeforest.net/category/wordpress  In the Wordpress category all themes for use with WordPress are listed.